# How to control war submodules build order in Maven?

Tags: maven, build, maven-3, war, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi-module project, for eg:

```
ROOT
 L_ A
 |   L_ A1 (jar)
 |   L_ A2 (pom)
 L_ B
     L_ B1 (jar)
     L_ B2 (war)
```

The ROOT always loads the module A in the reactor and there is a profile that loads the module B.

My problem is their build order. The module A2 is using `maven-assembly-plugin` to copy the war and other files to a folder. The order I need would be A1 > B1 > B2 > A2. How can I get this?

I can't put the B modules inside A2 - Maven complains the B modules are duplicate since they are loaded by another profile already. I can put B1 as a dependency of the assembly plugin and so move the build of A2 after B1. But I can't put B2 as a dependency because it is not a jar, I get an error.

Comment: Can you please make an example project on github or alike which shows your setup with profiles etc. ??

Comment: `The module A2 is using maven-assembly-plugin to copy the war and other files to a folder` can you explain in detail why you are using assembly-plugin to copy ?? Does not make sense... having WAR etc. that be deployed to tomcat/jboss or alike which is not the job of Maven.

Comment: The copy-ing is not for deployment purposes and makes sense, trust me

Comment: The question is about the order in a reactor, making a WAR of a submodule before executing a plugin on another submodule

Comment: Simple copying via assembly does not make sense. Furthermore define the dependencies between the modules correctly and don't use profiles to "load" modules that's simply wrong...

Comment: It would be helpful to create a full working example on github or alike...